Is it possible to check if the signature is empty in the backend?
I'm using the following Signature Pad package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/signature_pad
I am sending the <svg> element as a string to the backend. But even if it's empty, I still get an svg string.
Is there a way to check if the signature is empty or not using another way?

As indicated in the usage section, you can test whether the signature is empty like this:
signaturePad.isEmpty()

